# Require.js javascript file format

Tags: javascript, jasper-reports, require, visualize

I am trying to load a js file through require having structure like the following.

Though it is loading and working as expected, I want to ask whether the file format is right to be loaded with require?

```
!function(global){

  //js content

}(this)

visualize.__jrsConfigs__["userLocale"] = "en";

visualize.__jrsConfigs__["avaliableLocales"] = ["de", "en", "es", "fr", "it", "ja", "ro", "zh_TW", "zh_CN"];

if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
  define(["reporting"], function () {
     return visualize;
  });
}

var currentThemePath = "_themes/AEFCB57D/theme.css".split("/").slice(0, -1);
```